# Intersections of two great circles on a sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Suppose you have a great circle passing through points $A$ and $B$ on a sphere, and another great circle passing through points $C$ and $D$ on the sphere.  I want to find the two intersections of these two great circles.  How do I do that?

**Formulation**:  Assuming $A, B, C, D$ are given in rectangular coordinates, and that the radius of the sphere to be $1$, then the normal vector to the plane of the first great circle is

$ n_1 = A \times B $

and the normal vector to the plane of the second great circle is

$ n_2 = C \times D$

From the vector $n_1$ we can generate two unit vector $u_1, u_2$ such that the triple $u_1, u_2, n_1$ forms an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3 $.  Repeat the same thing with $n_2$, thus generating unit vectors $v_1, v_2$ such that the triple $v_1, v_2, n_2$ forms an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3 $.

Hence, the parametric equation of the first great circle is

$ C_1(t) = \cos t \ u_1 + \sin t \ u_2 $

and the parametric equation of the second great circle is

$ C_2(s) = \cos s \ v_1 + \sin s \ v_2 $

I want to find $t$ and $s$ such that $C_1(t) = C_2(s)$.

**My Attempt:**  Using matrix-vector notation, we have

$ C_1(t) = U \omega_1(t) $

$ C_2(s) = V \omega_2(s) $

where $U = [u_1, u_2], V = [v_1, v_2] $ are $3 \times 2 $ matrices, and $\omega_1(t)$ and $\omega_2(s)$ are $2 \times 1$ vectors defined as follows

$\omega_1(t) = [\cos(t) , \sin(t) ]^T$

$ \omega_2(s) = [\cos(s), \sin(s) ]^T $

Now we have to find $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ such that

$ U \omega_1 = V \omega_2 $

subject to $\omega_1^T \omega_1 = \omega_2^T \omega_2 = 1 $

Pre-multiply both sides by $V^T$, you get

$ V^T U \omega_1 = V^T V \omega_2 $

Since $v_1, v_2$ are orthogonal unit vectors, then $V^T V$ is equal to the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.  Therefore,

$ \omega_2 = V^T U \omega_1 $

Substitute this back.  This gives us,

$ U \omega_1 = V V^T U \omega_1 $

So that

$ (I_3 - V V^T) U \omega_1 = 0 $

Thus $\omega_1$ is in the null space of $(I_3 - V V^T ) U $.  Once we determine the direction of $\omega_1$ we impose $\omega_1^T \omega_1 = 1 $ to get its two possible values.

Note that $(I_3 - VV^T)$ is has rank $1$.  Therefore, $(I_3 - V V^T) U$ also has rank $1$.  In fact,

$I_3 - V V^T = {n_2 n_2}^T $

Hence,

$(I_3 - V V^T) U = n_2 [n_2^T u_1, n_2^T u_2] $

Recall that $\omega_1(t)=[\cos(t), \sin(t)]^T$

Hence, we require that

$ \cos(t) \ n_2^T u_1 + \sin(t) \ n_2^T u_2 = 0 $

It follows that

$ \tan(t) = - \dfrac{ n_2^T u_1 }{ n_2^T u_2 } $

And this gives two values for $t$ in $[0, 2 \pi) $ from which we compute the two intersection points.

This was the method I developed to solve this problem.

I appreciate any comments, hints, or alternative solutions that can be more efficient.

**EDIT:**  After a comment below by @user10354138, I realized all of the above is unnecessary.  The plane of the first great circle is given by

$ n_1^T r = 0 $

where $ r = [x, y, z]^T $

And the plane the second great circle is given by

$ n_2^T r = 0 $

So the intersection of the two planes is the line whose direction vector is

$ N = n_1 \times n_2 $

The two planes of the great circles pass through the origin, so the line of intersection is now given by

$r = \ell(t) = t N $

Intersecting this line with the sphere $r^T r = 1$ gives the two intersection points between the two great circles. That is

Solve for $t$ (both positive and negative) from

$ t^2 N^T N = 1 $

Then the intersection points are

$ P_i = t_i N $

Thank you @user10354138 !!

Comment: The process of finding $u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2$ via $n_1, n_2$ seems  a little circuitous for my tastes. If you just apply Gram-Schmidt to the vectors $A, B$ and $C, D$, you'll get $u_1, u_2, v_1, v_2$ more easily and mechanically; simply "finding" unit vectors orthogonal to $n_1, n_2$ will often involve Gram-Schmidt anyway, so cutting out the middleman seems more efficient.

Comment: Yes.  That makes sense.  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Basically, where the line $\langle(A\times B)\times(C\times D)\rangle$ intersects the sphere are the points common to the two great circles $AB$ and $CD$, so you just compute $(A\times B)\times (C\times D)$ and normalise.

Comment: Excellent remark.  Thank you @user10354138

Comment: If you know the center of the circle the two plans that include center and A,B and center and C,D will define the line that intersect the sphere which are your desired points.